# Hide Alert message while page loading using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, alert

I have an alert message box which displays when ng-repeat result is empty. Everything works, but my issue is when the page is loading the alert box is displayed. How do I hide it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Alert box code: <div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="reqItems == ''">
      {{nullMessage}}
    </div>

Comment: Did you try [ngCloack](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)??

Comment: It would be good if you could post the controller where is declared `reqItems`

Answer (score 0):

Try the ngCloak directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

`<div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="reqItems == ''" ng-cloak> {{nullMessage}} </div>`

If this doesn't work, you may need to post your HTML and JS code so we can better diagnose.